# ASP.NET MVC - Captcha as stand-alone assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've implemented CAPTCHA for a form submission page in my app as per code I got from *Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework* book.

He has a Tip in there that says "if you want to turn this into a reusable, distributable CAPTCHA component... all you have to do is to put the CaptchaHelper and CaptchaImageController classes into a stand-alone assembly."

What does this mean?

I was thinking that I'd just create a new MVC project, have this single controller in the controller folder, and the helper file in the Helper folder.  It compiles just fine.

I then include that project into my solution and have added references to this project in both of my other sub-projects (one for business layer, other for ui).

But when I try to render the page, the view cannot render the captcha image.  (btw, it worked just fine before I broke it out into a separate project.)

The view page can't seem to find the CAPTCHA controller.

I guess I need help in creating a stand-alone controller...

Thanks,
Scott

Error is:

> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service Captcha.CaptchaImageController was found
>   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.get_Item(Type service)
>   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve(Type service)
>   at WebUI.WindsorControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType) in
>       C:\work_aspx\PostHealthWellness\WebUI\WindsorControllerFactory.cs:line 48
>   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a standard Class Library project with the two files. Add the needed references(MVC...) to make it compile. Add the compiled dll as a reference to your main web application.

Comment: Yes, I did this, but I also had to register my external controller with Windsor.

Comment: Using info I found [here][1], I edited my WindsorControllerFactory.cs file to add:

    // Register controllers in external assemblies
    container.Kernel.AddComponent("ExternalResources", typeof(Captcha.CaptchaImageController), LifestyleType.Transient);



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163900/external-controllers-and-castle

Comment: So, I did this with the dlls, but then I had to add                              container.Kernel.AddComponent("ExternalResources", typeof(Captcha.CaptchaImageController), LifestyleType.Transient);                         to my WindsorControllerFactory class at the end of the main constructor.